# A way to access a google sheet from drive in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

I'm currently making two programs for work in Unity on two separate computers. I have managed to read a local text file on the main computer and upload the info into a google sheets document. For security reasons, I understand that it is not possible to then access the drive on the second computer and download the sheet as a csv file locally. Is there another way I can access the sheet data on the second computer from google drive without having to download it manually each morning?

Comment: First result on a very quick google search for ["Unity Google Drive API"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unity+Google+Drive+API) is e.g. [Elringus /
UnityGoogleDrive](https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive) .. what's wrong about that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- I suggest you create a shared folder on google drive, then set this folder to be publicly accessible.
- then you can upload files to this drive, and then download it else where

There is 1 problem with this, is that your info will be accessible publicly by anyone who has the link, this is a simple way to do it for testing for now.

Comment: I didn't think that was an option, I will definitely look further into that! Thanks so much I appreciate it :) it's been killing me for days! That's fine, where I work isn't really computer associated so no one will really know what to look for anyway, it's just a way to make life easier at work.